# When running a report on SSRS get error related to ASPState

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

We have reports on production on SSRS Sql Server reporting services

the reports were running correctly till yasterday! today when running any report get this error

Cannot open database "ASPState" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'.

why is this and how to solve it

Comment: this thing only affects afolder of reports

Answer (score 0):

If you were running fine until yesterday, then odds are something changed in your settings in IIS that has you logging in anonymously instead of impersonating someone, or the "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" used to have a user on your SQL server, and it was changed or removed.  Or that user's rights were changed.  Or something.

You should probably ask around to see if anyone changed any settings or configurations on either IIS or SQL Server.

Comment: The problem is i don't think we have a database called ASPState at all

Comment: Are you saving Session State to you SQL Databases?

Comment: Okay, well then I got nothing. :) Might want to take a look at the DB server that it's running against and the IIS server it's running on for a newly added database called ASPState. From what I can tell searching around, that database is used to store session state on your SQL server.  Things like this usually don't just happen without someone somewhere changing something.  And this definitely has the symptoms of a configuration issue.